# Redirect from different port to subdomain - htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache

I created a Digital Ocean instance to install WordPress website 5 days ago. I already have my own domain, and created DNS Subdomain `blog.example.com`. The server runs both nginx and apache so my Apache port is 8082. Below is what my actual WordPress URL looks like:

```
www.example.com:8082/wordpress/
```

Something which I have tried is below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com:8082/wordpress\
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/? http://$1.example.com [R=301,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Now my expected result is from

```
www.example.com:8082/wordpress\
```

to

```
blog.example.com
```

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file located? In the document root, or in the `/wordpress` subdirectory?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com:8082/wordpress\
> ```

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the value of the `Host` HTTP request header - this does not include the URL-path (ie. `/wordpress/`). But why have you also include a backslash (`\`) at the end, instead of a (forward) slash (`/`)? Is that just a typo? (Although you've also carried that through to the example below?)

> ```
> RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/? http://$1.example.com [R=301,NC,L]
> ```

Not quite sure what the idea behind this is, but this directive assumes that `blog` is present in the requested URL-path - but it's not in your example? And, unless you have multiple subdomain redirects, there's seemingly no need for the generalised match and substitution?

I would also question why you need the the conditions that check that the request does not map to a directory or a file. By checking that it does not map to a directory, it won't redirect `/wordpress/` (assuming this is a physical directory).

To redirect `www.example.com:8082/wordpress/` to `blog.example.com` as in your example (a single URL redirect<sup>***1**</sup>) then you would need to do something like the following instead, at the top of your *root* `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com:8082
RewriteRule ^wordpress/$ http://blog.example.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

If the `.htaccess` file is located inside the `/wordpress` subdirectory then change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to read `^$` instead of `^wordpress/$`

If `example.com:8082` and `blog.example.com` point to different areas of the filesystem then you can remove the condition (`RewriteCond` directive) altogether.

No need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper or `RewriteBase` directives here.

<sup>***1**</sup> Although I'm surprised you don't want to mass redirect all sub-URLs as well? ie. Redirect `www.example.com:8082/wordpress/<something>` to `blog.mydomain.com/<something>`. Or do you?